# How to return empty or null instead of throwing an exception

Tags: java

How to return empty or null instead of throwing an exception. This is what I am using right now, is there a more simpler way

```
   public UserExtension findByIdOrNull(String id) {

        try {
            return findById(id);
        }
        catch (NotFoundException ignore) {
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what's the error

Comment: Maybe it does not throw a `NotFoundException ` ?

Comment: also the statement "return null;" is not in the catch block

Comment: In your code, most probably the exception thrown by ```findbyId``` function is not ```NotFoundException```. you can change ti to ```Exception``` then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your return type in Optional. In this way, you don't need to throw null or exception. In the function call, you can check isPresent.

```
public Optional<UserExtension> findByIdOrNull(String id) {
    return Optional.of(findById(id));    
}
```

Comment: Note: Optionals are only available from Java onwards.

Comment: @leoOrion yeah sorry forgot to mention. If you are using after Java8 version

Comment: @leoOrion hopefully nobody uses older versions than java 8